# positioning elements in a certain place

Tags: html, css

I've been learning HTML and CSS for a little while now but I am pretty self taught so sorry if this seems to be a pretty basic question.

I have this container in the middle of my page (it's a carousel but I don't think that makes a difference) and I'm trying to position two things: a large word on top of it (inside a div) and navigation buttons below it. Currently, I've positioned them both there using `position: fixed;` and `top` and `left` elements. This isn't ideal of course because on mobile and devices of different widths these elements are in completely different positions.

Here's the HTML for the container and navigation buttons, the carousel controls are there too:

```
<div id="container">

<input hidden type="radio" name="carousel-control" id="button_a" checked/>
<input hidden type="radio" name="carousel-control" id="button_b"/>
<input hidden type="radio" name="carousel-control" id="button_c"/>
<input hidden type="radio" name="carousel-control" id="button_d"/>

    <div id="title">explore</div> /*the text I want on top*/
    <div id="carousel">
    <div class="p-wrapper">
                
        <section class="panel_a">
            <h2>Panel a</h2>
            <div class="headerdivider"></div>
            
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ornare faucibus diam id maximus. Fusce at efficitur nunc. Curabitur sed ullamcorper orci. Nam nulla enim, ultricies nec lectus a, commodo volutpat nisi. Pellentesque facilisis lacinia ante, eu pulvinar ante varius a. Fusce tincidunt efficitur tempor. Praesent pretium felis consectetur posuere sagittis. Sed luctus nisl non vestibulum semper. Vivamus mi velit, porttitor ac malesuada at, vulputate venenatis augue.</p>
            <p>Morbi faucibus, nisi ac vulputate mattis, turpis tortor maximus nibh, nec interdum lectus sem sit amet enim. Integer non nulla vitae ex gravida egestas. Fusce sodales neque ut erat tempor euismod. Quisque imperdiet rhoncus pellentesque. Fusce vitae efficitur dolor, nec laoreet lacus. Nulla orci purus, cursus sit amet posuere ac, ultrices sed dui. Ut bibendum, dui non euismod lobortis, mi neque pretium lacus, in pulvinar libero mauris eu sem. Morbi ut felis finibus, posuere risus sit amet, malesuada leo.</p>
            <p>Nulla quis molestie mi. Cras quis magna dolor. Suspendisse a scelerisque ligula, ullamcorper imperdiet justo. Ut sit amet nisl malesuada, varius turpis quis, convallis urna. Vestibulum sed odio eget lorem porta dapibus. Mauris augue sapien, scelerisque vel neque vitae, vulputate iaculis tellus. Sed accumsan egestas sem congue vehicula. Fusce quis blandit nibh, non bibendum lorem. Integer maximus mi non eros tincidunt pretium. Curabitur tempor nisi a aliquet dictum. Sed pellentesque venenatis ex ac fermentum. Aliquam vitae tincidunt urna.</p>
            <p>Nulla sagittis quis purus vitae consequat. Nullam pharetra dignissim tempus. Pellentesque egestas elit vel arcu condimentum euismod ut eu nisi. Fusce erat lectus, placerat quis egestas posuere, sollicitudin non ligula. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce vel leo ultrices, vehicula leo quis, semper quam. Cras mollis quis sem in tempor. Proin sed dui eu arcu efficitur pulvinar at sed leo. Donec rhoncus rhoncus est, eleifend posuere neque aliquet in.</p>
        </section>
                
        <section class="panel_b">
            <h2>Panel b</h2>
            <div class="headerdivider"></div>
            {block:AskEnabled}
            <p><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="190" src="http://www.tumblr.com/ask_form/spinningsilvers.tumblr.com" style="background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden;" id="ask_form"></iframe><!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('ask_form').allowTransparency=true;</script><![endif]--></p>{/block:AskEnabled}
        </section>
                
        <section class="panel_c">
            <h2>Panel c</h2>
            <div class="headerdivider"></div>
            <p>Fusce convallis arcu mauris, vitae semper ligula maximus vitae. Morbi a nibh id justo ullamcorper tincidunt. Aliquam et mollis mauris, eu varius metus. Praesent eget mi ac diam congue iaculis. Praesent accumsan euismod tempus. Aenean tempor libero et eros pellentesque molestie. Pellentesque malesuada ligula ut hendrerit laoreet. Ut turpis neque, tempor in ultrices sed, hendrerit ac leo. Nam placerat dolor sit amet ligula bibendum malesuada. Donec sagittis ultricies ex id mattis.</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Aliquam iaculis enim ut mi bibendum tincidunt.</li>
                <li>Nulla quis elit in lorem vulputate laoreet.</li>
                <li>Praesent non lacus euismod, ultricies lectus ac, vehicula arcu.</li>
                <li>Integer lobortis ipsum vitae velit mollis, at commodo ligula suscipit.</li>
            </ul>
            <p>Sed ut leo et mi tristique feugiat. Nunc fermentum diam mauris, in ultricies neque tincidunt dictum. Quisque ac odio dignissim, ornare enim condimentum, faucibus erat. Sed tortor turpis, imperdiet dignissim lacus eget, dignissim vehicula lorem. Mauris semper mi lacus, sit amet rutrum lacus tincidunt sed. Curabitur vel nisl eu magna placerat pretium. Curabitur malesuada sagittis tortor, eget volutpat mi pellentesque quis.</p>
        </section>
                
        <section class="panel_d">
            <h2>Panel d</h2>
            <div class="headerdivider"></div>
            <p>Aenean maximus accumsan mauris. Praesent rutrum vitae purus et mattis. Nunc at mi et diam pulvinar euismod. Curabitur interdum, leo quis tincidunt pharetra, risus nisl mollis velit, interdum consectetur justo orci in nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus elit turpis, tincidunt non dui et, molestie maximus nisl. Duis pretium eros sed ultricies convallis. Pellentesque vitae tempor lorem, eu laoreet metus. Vivamus sit amet lorem libero. Vestibulum tristique ligula in gravida volutpat. Sed facilisis ipsum velit, et pharetra nisi ullamcorper ut. Maecenas purus dui, tincidunt non ipsum vel, bibendum aliquam elit. Cras rutrum velit diam, semper aliquet libero posuere nec.</p>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec ut eleifend lacus. Sed fringilla ullamcorper justo, porttitor cursus nisl. Sed et mi aliquet, rutrum erat at, porttitor felis. Mauris consequat mauris id posuere dictum. Proin nec congue purus, nec rhoncus justo. Cras sit amet neque eu ex feugiat auctor at dignissim augue. Sed commodo tellus id erat lobortis, sit amet elementum felis commodo. Ut massa diam, tristique vel lacinia sed, vulputate eget mauris. Fusce lacinia bibendum iaculis.</p>
        </section>
                
    </div> <!-- // .p-wrapper -->
</div> <!-- // #carousel --> 

<div id="navigation"> /*the nav buttons that will go below*/
    <label for="button_a" class="label_a"> <span>about</span> </label>
    <label for="button_b" class="label_b"> <span>message</span> </label>
    <label for="button_c" class="label_c"> <span>navigate</span> </label>
    <label for="button_d" class="label_d"> <span>social</span> </label>
</div> <!-- // #navigation -->
```

Here's the CSS for the word I'm trying to put above:

```
#title {
    font-family:'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    font-size:40px;
    position:fixed;
    top:140px;
    left:135px;
}
```

Here's the CSS for the navigation that I'm trying to put below:

```
#navigation {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:175px;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

Here's a picture of
[what I'm looking to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWl7g.png) just with better code of course.

I've tried `position: absolute;` paired with `top: 0px;` and `left: 0px` and I tried putting the div for the words to go above in various spots but nothing's working. (Not sure this makes a difference but I'm working with Tumblr code here.) This is my first time posting here and as I mentioned I'm not too too advanced with coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap everything that belongs together actually together, meaning inside a wrapper-element. That way, you can simply use `display: flex` with `flex-flow: column` on their parent to lay them out in a column.

Then, with the `align-items`-property, you can say how/where they should align.
For the navigation I have overridden it with `align-self: stretch` so that I can center its content.
However, one could have also given the parent `align-items: stretch` (which is default), and the title `align-self: flex-start`. Both will give the expected result as long as `.carousel` is the widest element of the three.

As you see, by using a wrapper-element, you don't need to fiddle around with numbers to position them, and as a bonus, you group them together making it actually semantically clear that they belong together.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
section > .carousel {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
section > nav {
  align-self: stretch;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>explore</h1>
  <div class="carousel"></div>
  <nav>
    <a>Some link</a>
    <a>Another link</a>
    <a>A third link</a>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If I wanted to reduce the space between 'explore' and the carousel, is there a way to do that?

Comment: That space is there because of the default margin of `<h1> `, you can change that however you like.